# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=2}^{n}{\frac{i^k-1}{i^k+1}}$ for various values of $k$

Tags: limits, products

Let's consider the following function:
$$
f(n, k) = \prod_{i = 2}^{n}{\frac{i^k - 1}{i^k + 1}}
$$
I'm interested in the limit of $f$ as $n$ approaches infinity for various values of $k$.

I managed to calculate the limit for $k = 1$ (it's $2$) and $k = 3$ (it's $2/3$).

For other values of $k$ the limit seems to be irrational, but I only managed to approximate it with direct calculations.

My question:

> How to find the limit analytically for other $k$? What's so special about $3$ and $1$ being rational limits?

Comment: How did you get $2$ for $k=1$? The product is $2(n!)/(n+1)!$.

Comment: You may look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/681828/721644) related answer by Claude Leibovici.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $k=1$,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n,1) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n(n+1)} = 0. $$

When $k=2,3,\dots$, you may write

$$f(n,k)=\Biggl[\prod_{\omega\,:\,\omega^k=1}\frac{(n-\omega)!}{(1-\omega)!}\Biggr]\Bigg/\Biggl[\prod_{\omega\,:\,\omega^k=-1}\frac{(n-\omega)!}{(1-\omega)!}\Bigg],$$

where $s!=\Gamma(s+1)$. Then the Stirling's approximation shows that the limit as $n\to\infty$ is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,k)=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(1-e^{(2j-1)i\pi/k})!}{\prod_{j=1}^{k}(1-e^{2ji\pi/k})!}.$$

For even values of $k$ as well as $k=3$, this reduces to an elementary expression:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,2) &= \frac{\pi}{\sinh\pi}, \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,3) &= \frac{2}{3}, \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,4) &= \frac{\pi\sinh\pi}{\cosh(\sqrt{2}\pi) - \cos(\sqrt{2}\pi)}, \\
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n,6) &= \frac{\pi(\cosh(\sqrt{3}\pi)+1)}{3\sinh \pi (\cosh \pi - \cos(\sqrt{3}\pi) )}.
\end{align*}